# Highcharts - Passing in Color with JSON

Tags: json, highcharts

Currently, I'm using a back end process to create a JSON file for a 3d bar chart with HighCharts.

```
[{
     "name": "Town",
     "data": ["NorthCentral","NorthEast","SouthCentral","SouthEast","West"]
}, {
     "name": "Population",
     "data": [99.47,82,89,82,82]
}]
```

What I would like know is - can you pass in colors with each data point? for example:

```
[{
     "name": "Town",
     "data": ["NorthCentral","NorthEast","SouthCentral","SouthEast","West"]
}, {
     "name": "Population",
     "data": [{color: 'red',99.47},82,89,82,82]
}]
```

I have tried already with no luck. This might not be supported but I thought I would ask.

Comment: Please post what you have still tried, so that other can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 0
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5
}]
```

[A sample with line chart](http://jsfiddle.net/xqWp5/1/)